# raise by? from?

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

If the original premium is 100 USD, and the insurance company announced that it would be raised to minimum 105, and maximum 110, which one is correct?

1. The premium will rise **by** 5 to 10 percent.
2. The premium will rise **from** 5 to 10 percent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The premium will rise **by** 5 to 10 percent" is correct.

"The premium will rise **from** 5 to 10 percent" means that the premium was originally 5 percent of some amount (such as the amount being insured), and that the new premium will be 10 percent of the relevant amount.  If the amount being insured increased, the premium would more than double.

*[How to Lie with Statistics](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=0393310728)* (by Darrell Huff, pictures by Irving Geis) has lots of great examples of percentage changes.  The examples have pictures, and show how various prepositions affect the changes.